# Why is LD_PRELOAD usage discouraged?

Tags: c++, compilation, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I came across this piece of advice on the Google's [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) documentation page.

> You can use TCMalloc in applications you didn't compile yourself, by using LD_PRELOAD:
>
> ```
> $ LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so"
> ```
>
> LD_PRELOAD is tricky, and we don't necessarily recommend this mode of usage.

Why do they discourage LD_PRELOAD? Is something inherently wrong with it? Is normal linking more robust? How?

Comment: Well the documentation is suggesting one way of doing something, but they don't want people to go using "LD_PRELOAD" for <insert bad reasons here>.

Comment: Those bad reasons are what I want to understand. They only say it's tricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [ysdx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27311625/1392132)' answer, the value of `LD_PRELOAD` [will also be ignored](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) (for good reasons) for `setuid()`ed programs.

Depending on the use-case, this might be undesirable.  For example, you cannot write a shell script wrapper that exports `LD_PRELOAD` and then executes the actual program.

Answer (score 5):

When using `LD_PRELOAD`, the `tcmalloc` implementation will be used for any child process as well which may not be what you want.